# Pig Distributed cache

Tags: apache-pig, distributed-cache, pig-udf

What is the difference between `getShipFiles` & `getCacheFiles` in `EvalFunc` class?

Assuming any file specified in this method are available to `exec` method from distributed cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**getCacheFiles()
Allow a UDF to specify a list of hdfs files it would like placed in the distributed cache.**

**getShipFiles()
Allow a UDF to specify a list of local files it would like placed in the distributed cache.**

So getShipFiles get files from local files and Cache get them form HDFS.